# Rails 4: Link Thumbnailer Bad URI format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, url, uri

I am trying to use [Link Thumbnailer](https://github.com/gottfrois/link_thumbnailer) to fetch a title, image, and description from a recipe website and for some reason I keep getting a `BadUriFormat` error when I provide the website's URL.

In my view I have:

```
<% @recipes.each do |recipe| %>

  <tr>
    <td class="recipe-info">
        <%= image_tag LinkThumbnailer.generate(recipe.image_link).images.first.src.to_s %>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

...and the recipe in this example is:

```
#<Recipe:0x007fe48394a358> {
    :id => 1,
    :name => "test",
    :image_link => "http://paleoleap.com/simple-beef-shish-kabobs/"
}
```

Here is my error:

```
ETHON: started MULTI
ETHON:         performed EASY effective_url=http://res.cloudinary.com/paleoleap/image/upload/f_auto,q_90/v1459886762/j-paleo/simple-beef-shish-kabob-main.jpg response_code=200 return_code=write_error total_time=0.04831799999999997
ETHON: performed MULTI
ETHON: started MULTI
ETHON:         performed EASY effective_url=http://paleoleap.com/pictures/icons/servings.png response_code=200 return_code=write_error total_time=0.053881
ETHON: performed MULTI
ETHON: started MULTI
ETHON:         performed EASY effective_url=http://paleoleap.com/pictures/icons/prep3.png response_code=200 return_code=write_error total_time=0.050677
ETHON: performed MULTI
ETHON: started MULTI
ETHON:         performed EASY effective_url=http://paleoleap.com/pictures/icons/cooking4.png response_code=200 return_code=write_error total_time=0.044727
ETHON: performed MULTI
ETHON: started MULTI
ETHON:         performed EASY effective_url=http://res.cloudinary.com/paleoleap/image/upload/f_auto,q_90/v1459886762/j-paleo/simple-beef-shish-kabob-preparation.jpg response_code=200 return_code=write_error total_time=0.048975
ETHON: performed MULTI
  Rendered recipes/index.html.erb within layouts/application (510.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1040ms (ActiveRecord: 7.3ms)

LinkThumbnailer::BadUriFormat (LinkThumbnailer::BadUriFormat):
  app/views/recipes/index.html.erb:46:in `block in _app_views_recipes_index_html_erb___148801017206438179_70110103402900'
  app/views/recipes/index.html.erb:26:in `_app_views_recipes_index_html_erb___148801017206438179_70110103402900'
```

When I fetch the image in my controller by performing `LinkThumbnailer.generate(Recipe.find(1))` it runs without a problem.

Here is the success:

```
ETHON: started MULTI
ETHON:         performed EASY effective_url=http://res.cloudinary.com/paleoleap/image/upload/f_auto,q_90/v1459886762/j-paleo/simple-beef-shish-kabob-main.jpg response_code=200 return_code=write_error total_time=0.056864
ETHON: performed MULTI
ETHON: started MULTI
ETHON:         performed EASY effective_url=http://paleoleap.com/pictures/icons/servings.png response_code=200 return_code=write_error total_time=0.04847
ETHON: performed MULTI
ETHON: started MULTI
ETHON:         performed EASY effective_url=http://paleoleap.com/pictures/icons/prep3.png response_code=200 return_code=write_error total_time=0.04541
ETHON: performed MULTI
ETHON: started MULTI
ETHON:         performed EASY effective_url=http://paleoleap.com/pictures/icons/cooking4.png response_code=200 return_code=write_error total_time=0.039456
ETHON: performed MULTI
ETHON: started MULTI
ETHON:         performed EASY effective_url=http://res.cloudinary.com/paleoleap/image/upload/f_auto,q_90/v1459886762/j-paleo/simple-beef-shish-kabob-preparation.jpg response_code=200 return_code=write_error total_time=0.0386
ETHON: performed MULTI
```

What's the difference between calling the `generate` method on `recipe.image_link` in my loop, vs. calling it on a specific `Recipe` in the controller?

Comment: I see that you are looping on an array of `@recipes`, can you please display the value of that array? I'm suspecting a blank value in your array which would trigger the `BadUriFormat` exception

Comment: Oh jeezus.  I had a feeling it was something silly like that.  My second `recipe` had no `:image_link`.

Answer (score 0):

Writing down my comment as an answer. Your `@recipes` array must contain a blank value which cause the gem to raise the `BadUriFormat` exception.

Also, I would suggest the following options to avoid unnecessary computation by the gem when fetching a website:

`LinkThumbnailer.generate(url, attributes: [:images], image_limit: 1, image_stats: false)`

- `attributes` -- will tell the gem to only care about images
- `image_limit` -- will tell the gem to only fetch one image. However it might not be the best one since it will not try to fetch more than one image.
- `image_stats` -- will tell the gem to not care about images size and type